# Отправка изображения методом POST

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, post, загрузка

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста.
Мне нужно сделать следующее

> Передайте файлы на адрес upload_url, полученный в предыдущем пункте, сформировав POST-запрос с полями file1-file5. Эти поля должны содержать изображения в формате multipart/form-data.

Вопрос, как сформировать данный запрос имея upload_url ?
И да, хочу отправлять картинку которая уже лежит у меня в корне, например 1.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [`photos.getUploadServer`](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getUploadServer) вернет вам JSON-объект, в поле `upload_url` которого содержится адрес для загрузки фотографии. Вам надо сформировать на этот адрес POST-запрос, засунув в поля `file1`-`file5` картинки, которые вы хотите загрузить. Лучше всего с этим справится cURL. Вот пример:

```
// Инициализируем cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Поля POST-запроса
$parameters = [
    'file1' => new CURLFile('path/to/1.jpg')  // PHP >= 5.5.0
    // 'file1' => '@path/to/1.jpg' // PHP < 5.5.0
];

// Ссылка, куда будем загружать картинку - это upload_url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);

// Говорим cURL, что это POST-запрос
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// Говорим cURL, какие поля будем отправлять
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);

// Говорим cURL, что нам нужно знать, что ответит сервер, к которому мы будем обращаться
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Выполняем cURL-запрос. В этой переменной будет JSON-ответ от ВКонтакте
$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);

// Закрываем соединение
curl_close($ch);
```

Затем вам необходимо вызвать метод [`photos.save`](https://vk.com/dev/photos.save), передав в него данные, которые вы получили при загрузке фотографии.