# Отправить изображение post jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vkontakte-api, post

Пытаюсь загрузить изображение на сервер вк методом POST, но не получается. Вот код:

```
VK.api('wall.getPhotoUploadServer', {}, function(data) {
if (data.response) {
    upload_url = data.response.upload_url; //адрес для запроса
    alert( upload_url );
    $.post(
        upload_url,
        {photo: 'http://zelenyar.ru/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C.jpg' },
        function(json) {
            hash = json.hash;
            alert( hash ); //не выводит
        },
        'json'
    );
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы должны передавать не ссылку на изображение, а отправлять само изображение в формате multipart/form-data.
2. Вы не сможете осуществить это на браузерном JavaScript из-за проблем с [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Загружайте изображение на свой сервер и там уже отправляйте картинку во ВК. Примерную процедуру загрузки картинки на PHP с помощью cURL я описал в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586032/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-post/586093#586093).

Comment: Можно уточнить? Отправлять само изображение в формате multipart/form-data на jvascript тоже нельзя? Или вы только про изображение с другого сайта?

Comment: Нельзя. CORS вам не позволит этого сделать.